# Can I log specific queries on Bind 9?

Tags: domain-name-system, logging, bind

I'd like to know which hosts make a specific DNS query, and at what times. Is there any way to get logs this specific on Bind 9?

For example, I might want to log all `A` queries for `xyzzy.net`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the right sort of channel stanza in your logging{} block in named.conf.

```
        channel "client" {
            file "/var/log/client_named.log";
            severity info;
            print-time yes;
        };
```

would probably do the trick.  That should get you this sort of data:

```
22-Apr-2011 12:06:53.294 client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#56202: view external-in: query: st.in.multi.surbl.org IN A +
```

EDIT:  Warning - enabling this sort of logging will generate very large log files very quickly, and could easily fill up your disk without having some sort of log rotation/compression, and is probably best suited to a brief data-gathering session, rather than a permanent configuration.

If that (along with post-processing the resulting log file) is too much, you could do this using a tool like tcpdump.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 dst port 53 | egrep 'A' | egrep 'xyyzyy.com'
```

or even better, writing a filter to match on only the right bits of the DNS packet that you want to filter on (the A? type in this case)

Probably easier, though, is to use a tool like dnstop.  [dnstop webpage](http://dns.measurement-factory.com/tools/dnstop/) will do all the protocol decoding for you, and IIRC you can filter it's output using -n to limit what it captures to a single domain.

Comment: I don't see how that helps. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're trying to do.  The answer is, I believe, no, but you can get there with post-processing the logs that you get from my original response.  Like "cat logfile | egrep xyzzy.net | awk '{print $8" "$10"} | egrep 'A'"

Comment: I don't want to generate that much log.

Comment: That certainly is an issue.  You could also do this inline, as it were, without generating any logs. I'll edit the original answer to talk about that.

Comment: Edited to add some techniques using tcpdump or dnstop.

Comment: I would be very careful to set up logging like this without any syslog shuffling the logfiles. DNS requests fill up log files blazingly fast.

Comment: Good point regarding huge log files generated by logging queries - I was assuming that this was for a brief period of time, but perhaps that's not an assumption I should have made.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that that's _not_ the case. I need this thing going for days. :-( If it were a FreeBSD, I could make newsyslogd pipe the log through a grep... I'll see if rsyslogd has anything like that. Thanks for the answer, anyway. I'll check dnstop out.

Answer (score 2):

No, the [logging statements](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/logging.html) do not support filters. You could send Bind logs to syslog and then filter for only the client IP and A record within your syslog rules. That's probably the simplest method.